# Add UISegmentedControl in table cell programmatically with clear background

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, grouped-table

I have grouped table view. I want to add UISegmentedControl in table cell with clear background so that it will be displayed as FOOTER . How can I do this? I tried using clearColor. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet here? That would help us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background view with a clear `UIView` object like so:

```
UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[clearView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self setBackgroundView:clearView];
[clearView release];
```

And make sure you set cell selection style to none.

*Edit: added some square brackets*